# UK Tourist Visa - Visited countries in 10 years

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, us-residents

I am an Indian citizen living in USA on work visa (L-1). I am applying for UK tourist visa.

In visa application it asks:

> How many times have you visited the following places in the past 10 years?
>
> - Australia
> - Canada
> - New Zealand
> - USA
> - European Economic Area (do not include travel to the UK)

Since I live in US, every time I enter back in US from trip to India, does that count a trip to US? Or since I am US resident (temporary resident) I shouldn't count it as a trip to US?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in doubt about including something on a visa application, include it. The UK and the US share immigration data, and UKVI will know about your US entries. If you don't mention them, UKVI may think you're not being honest.

You should also mention in the application that you currently live in the US on an L-1 work visa. This supports your application by showing a good reason for you to leave the UK after touring the UK.

Comment: _IF_ the application has room for comments, I would omit USA from "visited" and explain in the comments that I live and work there.  I would _not_ trust that to a separate sheet, which would likely get misplaced.

Comment: @WGroleau That makes very good sense, and I agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should. You *live* in the US, not just visiting.

Comment: The question is whether he should or not.  Clearly this _is_ an answer, although I think the other answer is better.